# MYSQL Creating table as select with xase statement converting field to numbered value

Tags: mysql

I have the following MYSQL query which creates table as select statement but having a case statment to change field formats to numbered fields to compare:

```
CREATE TABLE wm.bochg
AS
SELECT 
wca.bochg.BochgID,
wca.bochg.SecID,
wca.bochg.OldOutValue,
wca.bochg.NewOutValue,
case when NewOutValue+0.0 >= OldOutValue+0.0 then NewOutValue ELSE '' END AS test2
from wca.bochg
WHERE
wca.bochg.SecID in (select secid from client.pfisin where accid = 416)

AND (wca.bochg.BochgID is null or wca.bochg.BochgID =
(select subbochg.BochgID from wca.bochg as subbochg
where subbochg.secid=bochg.secid
AND subbochg.Actflag <> 'D'
AND subbochg.NewOutValue+0.0 >= subbochg.OldOutValue+0.0
order by subbochg.BochgID desc limit 1)
or wca.bochg.BochgID is NULL);
```

However I am getting warnings when this is created saying:
'Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '' '

This is due to my case statment and the and clause within my subquery. Is there a way to cater for this issue and get rid of the warning message above going forward? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing datatypes in the case statement. Use something else than a string '' for the ELSE part (NULL, 0 or anything that suits your purpose).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately did not resolve the issue for me I have ammended my case statment as follows:

`case when NewOutValue+0.0 >= OldOutValue+0.0 then NewOutValue+0.0 ELSE 0 END AS test2`

The new field created is now a DOUBLE But same warnings as above persist.

Comment: Please show the description of the wca.bochg-table and the MySQL version you are using.